html2pptxgenjs does not seem to work with angular browser-esbuild
I have updated angular to 18 using its new features, like changing the builder from browser to browser-esbuild and now getting this error during build
(it was working fine with the browser builder)
[ERROR] Could not resolve "fs"
node_modules/css/lib/stringify/source-map-support.js:9:17: var fs = require('fs');
The package "fs" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.
it builds if I modify stringify like this (node_modules/css/stringify/index.js)
comment the code which loads fs from source-map-support - locally (I do not even need this sourcemap functionality, anyway)
if (options.sourcemap) { var sourcemaps = require('./source-map-support'); sourcemaps(compiler);
however, this is not feasible in production
any help is appreciated regarding this build issue
I have searched the issue with google, found some similar issues with no replies/solutions
related post
Converting HTML text string to pptx slide using PptxGenJS
